# Echo -n With String argument printing the "-n" part, even though not within quotation marks

Tags: bash, echo

I've been learning how to script in bash, but I'm coming across a frustrating bug. In the below code, which just runs to print 10 rows and ten with ten columns, whenever the  `echo -n "$j "` runs, the output prints out both a new line and the "-n" argument to the `echo` command.

The echo command and the echo -n both work perfectly fine on their own, but for some reason, don't work within this script... Thank you in advance

```
    #Nested for loop

    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    do
    echo -n "Row $i: "

    for j in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    do
            sleep 1
            echo -n "$j  "
    done

    echo #Outputs new line
    done
```

Output looks like this...

`-n Row 1`

`-n 1`

`-n 2`
... And so on

Comment: There are multiple different implementations of `echo`: a shell builtin command (possibly different for each shell), and `/bin/echo`. Some recognize `-n`; others don't. Consider using the `printf` command instead; it's much more consistent across different implementations. Meanwhile, does your script have a `#!` line at the top, if so what does it look like, and how exactly are you executing the script?

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double on both **echo** statements.

Comment: @arif, totally wrong advice: single quotes prevent variable expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Some implementations of `echo` interpret `-n` as meaning "don't add a linefeed at the end", but others just treat it as part of the string to print. It can even be different between different versions of the same implementation! According to the [Single Unix Specification description of `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), "It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted."

IIRC, the version of bash that shipped with one version of OS X (10.5.0 maybe?) treated `-n` as part of the string to print, and a bunch of my scripts broke.

So I learned to use `printf` instead. It's slightly more complicated than `echo`, but far more portable and predictable. The tricky thing is that the first argument is a format string that says how to print the rest of the arguments. To replace a standard `echo "somestring"` command, you'd use `printf "%s\n" "somestring"`. For `echo -n "somestring"`, just leave the `\n` out of the format string: `printf "%s" "somestring"`. So in your case:

```
printf "%s" "$j  "
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code on my system, and it seems to work correctly in bash.  However, I do get the exact error that you described when I run it in straight sh.  Assuming that you are running this on a Mac, try running `/bin/bash` before running your script.

Assuming that your script is in a file, you can also add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script (this tells the computer to execute it with bash).

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried restarting bash, but even then (and the addition of #!/bin/bash, the program still seems to be having a slight error. I'll use others' suggestions and learn printf(), but thank you anyway for the suggestion.