# How to make two echo string in the same line?

Tags: bash

How to make two echo strings in the same line?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "A"
echo "B" | grep B
```

result is:

```
A
B
```

but I want it to be:

`AB`

Comment: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the line break in the first echo call with `echo -n`

Comment: Depending on what shell you're using, what mode it's in, and various other things, `echo -n` might omit the newline... or it might just print "-n" as part of its output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644/echo-n-with-string-argument-printing-the-n-part-even-though-not-within-quot) and [here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/). I once had a bunch of scripts break because an OS update changed the behavior of `echo -n`. I'd recommend `printf %s "B"` instead (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)).