# bash script : echo does not recognize arguments

Tags: bash, echo

I have a bash script (#!/bin/bash) with this line :

```bash
echo -ne "$display|\r"
```

but uppon execution what is displayed :

```
$ sh myScript.sh

-ne |
```

I tried to force the interpretation with reverse apostrophe, and in my command line the -ne options work perfectly.

Comment: By using `sh` to run the script, it's probably not running in `bash`.

Comment: Make the file executable, and run it using `./myScript.sh` *(No call to `sh`)*

Comment: Different versions of `echo` (or even a single version in different modes) are hopelessly inconsistent about interpreting options (like `-ne`). It's better to avoid them entirely, and use `printf` instead (in this case, either `printf '%b|\n' "$display"` if you want escape sequences in `$display` interpreted, or `printf '%s|\n' "$display"` if you don't). See ["Echo -n With String argument printing the '-n' part, even though not within quotation marks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644) and ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Comment: While the above comments are correct (you are not using bash, **and** we don't know exactly **which** echo version you are using), it could also be that you have aliased `echo` to something else. First, run the script with bash (using _bash  myScript.sh_). If you still get that strange output, do inside your script a `type echo`, so that you see which _echo_ you are executing. Also it might make sense to tell us which operating system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ty for all the response.

what did worked :

- run with `./script.sh`
- run with `bash script.sh`
- using printf

So indeed the shebang does not matter if executing the script with any shell binary.

for information :

```
antoine[01:36]:~$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

type echo
echo -ne "something"
antoine[01:36]:~$ sh script.sh 
echo is a shell builtin
-ne something
antoine[01:37]:~$ bash script.sh 
echo is a shell builtin
somethingantoine[01:37]:~$ 
antoine[01:37]:~$ ./script.sh 
echo is a shell builtin
somethingantoine[01:37]:~$
```