# Print variables read from file to file without newline

Tags: bash

I am reading in a list of variables, then manipulating them, then printing them to file in various formats. But the variables come with a newline, and nothing in my bash arsenal can touch it.

Here is input.txt:

```
1
2
3
```

The bash script:

```
echo -n "" > output.txt
while read p; do
  echo -n ${p} | xargs >> output.txt
done <input.txt
```

I don't want there to be any newlines in output.txt, I want it to be:

```
123
```

But it's:

```
1
2
3
```

With a \r\n plaguing each line. How can I remove them?

Comment: `tr -d '\r\n' < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: The line breaks are being added by `xargs`, so just remove it from the pipeline. Also, [`echo -n` is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644/echo-n-with-string-argument-printing-the-n-part-even-though-not-within-quot/35716306); use `printf '%s' "${p}"` instead. And there's no reason to redirect each command to the output file separately; just remove the first `echo -n ""` and the redirect within the loop, and add `>output.txt` after the `done`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @Shawn This is a simplification, the question says that he's processing the values after reading them, not just writing directly from the input to the output.

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to remove `\r` characters from the file before processing it. `read` will remove the newlines when reading the line.

Comment: W.r.t. "\r\n plaguing each line" see [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375), [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375), and [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the carriage returns is to add that character to IFS when reading lines from the file:

```bash
IFS+=$'\r'
while read -r line; do
  # do stuff with $line
  printf '%s' "$line"
done < input.txt > output.txt
```