# Bash script and shell itself does not give me the same output

Tags: bash, shell

This is the series of commands I want to run

```
vlanIdDec=69
vlanIdBin=$(awk -v vlanIdDec=$vlanIdDec 'BEGIN {s = sprintf("%*s", vlanIdDec, ""); gsub(".", "0", s); printf s"1"}')
vlanIdHex=$(echo $vlanIdBin | perl -lpe '$_=pack"B*",$_' | xxd -i | tr -d ', \n' | sed 's/0x/\\x/g' | sed 's/\\x0a//g')
vlanIdBase64=$(echo -e -n $vlanIdHex | base64 | tr -d '\n') && echo $vlanIdBase64
```

When I run the commands above one by one in command line, using `export`, I get the value which is `AAAAAAAAAAAE` at the end. However, When I put this series of commands inside a script file

```
#!/bin/sh

vlanIdDec=69

# Convert decimal VLAN ID to binary
vlanIdBin=$(awk -v vlanIdDec=$vlanIdDec 'BEGIN {s = sprintf("%*s", vlanIdDec, ""); gsub(".", "0", s); printf s"1"}')

# Convert binary VLAN ID to hexadecimal
vlanIdHex=$(echo $vlanIdBin | perl -lpe '$_=pack"B*",$_' | xxd -i | tr -d ', \n' | sed 's/0x/\\x/g' | sed 's/\\x0a//g')

# Convert hexadecimal VLAN ID to base64
vlanIdBase64=$(echo -e -n $vlanIdHex | base64 | tr -d '\n')

echo "Decimal VLAN ID: $vlanIdDec"
echo "Binary VLAN ID: $vlanIdBin"
echo "Hexadecimal VLAN ID: $vlanIdHex"
echo "Base64 VLAN ID: $vlanIdBase64"
```

This is the output I get which is wrong.

```
Decimal VLAN ID: 69
Binary VLAN ID: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
Hexadecimal VLAN ID: \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04
Base64 VLAN ID: LWUgLW4gXHgwMFx4MDBceDAwXHgwMFx4MDBceDAwXHgwMFx4MDBceDA0Cg==
```

WHat's the problem here? I tried to put commands inside a function but it didn't work. Another thing that I also implemented this series of commands in a Go program but I didn't get the same output again too. What's wrong here?

Comment: If you really want to get a base64 of binary data with several leading NUL then you want to call `base64` with file as input IMHO

Comment: Also, are you sure the algorithm you use for the binary id is correct? You can get the same output with much easier: `perl -e "print 0 x $vlanIdDec,1"`

Comment: The version of `echo` the script uses is printing the "-e -n " as part of its output, and not translating the hex characters. Using `echo` with options or anything with escapes is a compatibility nightmare; use `printf` instead. See ['Echo -n With String argument printing the "-n" part, even though not within quotation marks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644), ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803), and many other questions from people having similar problems. Also, use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) on your script.

Comment: I don't understand what's the corresponding parameters or arguements for printf If I want to get the same output as If I am runing 'echo -e -n'

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Replace it with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and you'll get the same output as you get from the interactive bash session.

Why is that?
Because `echo` in `sh` (which is probably `dash` or something similar) doesn't support `-e`.

Comment: @baris: How do you run the script?

Comment: I have to use 'sh' unfortunately. I did try and with bash it did work. Couldn't find corresponding command, etc. for the 'echo -e -n' in sh

Comment: As you already use `perl`, replace the `echo` with `echo "$vlanIdHex" | perl -pe 'chomp;s/\\x(..)/chr hex $1/ge'`