# Encoding text to Base64 in Bash and PowerShell has different outcome

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, unix, base64

I was reading [this article](https://goayxh.medium.com/powershell-script-decode-base64-string-6ac8b3622582) about how to encode text in Bash and PowerShell.

In the article there are 2 examples:

Using Bash (CLI) on macOS / Linux

```
echo "Hooked on phonics worked for me" | base64
```

Which gives as result: `SG9va2VkIG9uIHBob25pY3Mgd29ya2VkIGZvciBtZQo=`

Using PowerShell (CLI) on Windows

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Hooked on phonics worked for me"))
```

Which gives as result: `SG9va2VkIG9uIHBob25pY3Mgd29ya2VkIGZvciBtZQ==`

Can you spot the difference?

Why do I have 2 `==` at the end of the PowerShell Base64 encoding?

Comment: The first example has a trailing linefeed (0A) on the end. See linked Q/A

Comment: Thank you @jps, how did you find that? Because I cannot see it in plain text

Comment: It's a common issue with `echo`-based solutions. `echo` adds a trailing newline to its output by default because its most common use case is writing strings to a terminal or file for a human reader where the automatic newline is convenient, but that means you have to remove the newline (via the `-n` option) if you want the output to be consumable by a command that is sensitive to it. This is one reason why `printf` is often preferred, you get more control over the exact output. `printf 'Hooked on phonics worked for me' | base64` gives the same output as the Powershell version.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani The linked answer (written by me) explains that. You can see when you decode the base64 string to hex-ascii.

Comment: `echo -n` isn't reliable or portable, since some versions just print "-n " as part of their output (in addition to the unwanted newline). Use `printf %s "Hooked on phonics worked for me"` instead. See ['Echo -n With String argument printing the "-n" part, even though not within quotation marks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644/echo-n-with-string-argument-printing-the-n-part-even-though-not-within-quot) and ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)