# Why would openssl "verify" succeed every time with "source" but fail 80% of the time in a script?

Tags: bash, openssl

The following script works every time if I `source ./script.sh` but fails about 80% of the time if I execute it directly as `./script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
signing_input="Hi."
signature=$(echo -n "$signing_input" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem)
echo -n "$signing_input" | openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature <(echo -n "$signature")
```

So if I "source" that or run line-by-line, I always get: `Verified OK`

... but if I run it in a script I usually but not always get: `Error verifying data`

I get the same results if I save the signature to a file first.

I generated the `.pem` files this way:

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout -out private.pem
openssl ec -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

... and it doesn't matter if I reuse them or regenerate them every time.

I'm on a Mac M1 running iTerm2 with zsh.

Comment: If your shell is `zsh`  and you source it, you are not using `bash`, which is used by shebang

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem here, but `echo -n` is unpredictable -- depending on the shell, its mode(s), version of `echo`, etc it may just print "-n " as part of its output. Use `printf '%s' "$whatever"` instead. See ['`echo -n` With String argument printing the "-n" part, even though not within quotation marks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644/echo-n-with-string-argument-printing-the-n-part-even-though-not-within-quot), ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), and many other similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this really programming or development? I'm not sure, but I'll call it borderline unless the voting community decides otherwise.

**That's binary data** -- which sometimes includes 'null' (zero-valued) bytes. The ECDSA signature format for a curve group with order very close to 2^256 (which secp256k1 is) has 6 metadata bytes that are never zero, 0-2 padding bytes that are always zero when present and at least one is present 75% minus epsilon of the time, and almost always 64 bytes that except for two are indistinguishable from uniform random so at least one of them is zero 1-(1-1/256)^62 = 21.5463% of the time independent of the padding bytes -- thus 1-(1-.75)(1-.215463) = 80.3866% is the probability of at least one zero byte in such a signature.

**And `bash` can't handle null bytes in a variable**, so your `$signature` value is mangled and wrong, and verification fails. Modern versions of `bash` give a warning when this happens -- did you ignore it, or is yours ancient?

There is also a chance that the signature data ends in a newline byte (value 0x0A) (or even more than one) in which case command substitution `$(...)` removes it (or them) -- but only negligibly more than 1/256 ~ 0.4%, and given the chance of a null earlier, this adds only ~ 0.1% to the chance of mangling.

When you `source` the file it is executed by `zsh` NOT by `bash` (the shebang is ignored) and `zsh` DOES handle null bytes, so it mostly works -- but in the 0.4% case of a trailing newline zsh will also fail.

If you instead write to a file and read back, that will work in both/all shells always. Or if you encode to (and decode from) a form that doesn't use nulls (and ignores newlines), like base64:

```
signature=$(echo -n "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private | openssl base64 -e)
echo -n "$data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public -signature <(echo $signature | openssl base64 -d)
# base64 never contains chars that need quoting, and adding newline to it is fine 
# (in fact the base64 -e command included a trailing newline which $(...) _removed_)
```

Hex is also okay, but can't be done by `openssl` alone, and I don't know which other program(s) I can rely on your system having.

Comment: Fantastic! I learned a lot from your answer. And it doesn't feel like an upvote is enough for your efforts, so, publicly, thank you very much. 

Answer (score 1):

As it's the variable `signature` which causes problem, you can bypass it with :

```
#!/bin/bash

signing_input="Hi."
echo -n "$signing_input" | openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature\
  <(echo -n "$signing_input" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem)
```

This should work with `source` and without.