# Can a bash script run two processes in one line?

Tags: bash, batterylevel

I was wondering if there is any way of making both of these commands execute in the same line.

```
echo "Percentage: " ; pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%"
```

when I run this shell script it returs both fine, but in different lines.

Like this:

```
Percentage: 
81%
```

I tried all that I knew (again I'm starting out I'm a newb) I tried using ||, &&, |, and ;, as well.

Comment: `echo -n "Percentage: "`  wil not add a newline at the end of the outputed text.(see: `man echo`)

Comment: It's important to distinguish one line of source code from one line of output. Most people who see "in one line" think a request is for the former, when what you're asking for is the latter.

Comment: BTW, `echo "Percentage: $(pmset -g batt | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+%')"` is another way to get to your goal. (`\d` is not reliable in `grep -E`, as it's a PCRE extension, but `grep -E` is only guaranteed to support [POSIX ERE syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions))

Comment: `echo -n` is inconsistent -- it might omit the newline, or it might print "-n " as part of its output, depending on... it's complicated. Just use `printf "%s" "Percentage: "`  (or just `printf "Percentage: "`) instead. See ['Echo -n With String argument printing the "-n" part, even though not within quotation marks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712644/echo-n-with-string-argument-printing-the-n-part-even-though-not-within-quot) and ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: @Luuk, ...see Gordon's comment above, and also the "APPLICATION USAGE" and "RATIONALE" sections of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: OK I should have thought of `printf ....`

Comment: But stil, my suggestion is not wrong (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html#:~:text=Do%20not%20output%20the%20trailing%20newline.)  if only works when echo is part of the coreutils of gnu.

Comment: @Luuk, [echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command)) is a Bash [builtin command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) (see [Bash Reference Manual - echo](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-echo).  The `-n` option will work in any Bash code where `echo` hasn't been overridden (e.g. by defining a function called `echo`).  However, it's better to use `printf` instead of `echo` in general.  See the links in other comments.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Syntactically, you can **write** several commands in one line (by separating them with a semicolon), or write them in several lines (i.e. separating them with a newline character). **Executing** in one line does not make sense. For _executing_, you can ask whether you want to run two commands in parallel or sequentially, but this is unrelated to whether you type them into the same line or in different lines.